# How do we understand the command: "git checkout commit_id ."

Tags: git, git-checkout

I understand that `git checkout commit_id` will move the `head` to the `commit_id` and I will get an detached head and my working space will be overwritten by the `commit_id`.

Today I found another `git checkout`: `git checkout commit_id .`. This dot gives me a different thing. It seems that it overwrites my working space and the index of git with the `commit_id` whereas the `head` isn't moved.

How could I understand this command? Why does the dot stop the moving of `head`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git checkout could be used to revert files to a specific revision if given a path.

In this case, you are reverting the whole current directory to the version it used to have at `commit_id`

From the [git documentation about checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.6.2.3):

> When <paths> are given, this command does not switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file, or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit).